# Popping up errors: Publisher cannot print the high-resolution version of this graphic

Tags: pdf, office365, export, microsoft-publisher

I get this error on MS Publisher 365:

> Publisher cannot print the high-resolution version of this graphic. To
> continue printing using the low-resolution version of this graphic,
> click OK. To stop printing now, click Cancel.

How do I know which images cause this? There are hundreds of images in the document. The document size is about 80 MB. I searched on the web, yet haven't found the reason - even [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other/error-publisher-cannot-print-the-high-resolution/70e6355a-d7b7-4b82-b01a-31fcca9c4ec3) page on the official Microsoft forum doesn't solve the question.

The error happens when I go File → Export → Create PDF

[image]

You may watch the video capture of this in action: https://youtu.be/ZG_hAaDNNoo

As you may see, the dialog pops up 15 times and I have to click OK each time. How could I solve the cause of this annoying dialog?

Details: the resulting pdf file is 20 MB, 126 pages, page size is 8,5 x 11" (21,59 x 27,54 cm), if that matters.

Comment: 'How do I know which images cause this?" - I assume you have more than 15 images in the document?

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, I edited the question: there are hundreds of images in the document

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know Publisher have limited save a large page to PDF and the limit size is 500 MB.

Comment: I edited: the pdf size is 20 MB, page format is 8,5x11". But the point is, seems there are some images that cause the problem. And there isn't a tip on which images cause it

Comment: The link in the question already refers to the 500 MB document size limit, so the answer doesn't add any new information that HoRn doesn't already know.